# Using firebase configuration in a golem app

Tags: r, firebase, golem

I am new to using golem framework for R shiny app. In my app, I use firebase authentication using the R package `firebase`. So, I have firebase configuration in a r script `fct_helpers.R` which is located inside the `R` folder. Following is provided in configuration:

```
firebase::firebase_config(api_key = "API KEY",
                          project_id = "ID",
                          app_id = "APP ID",
                          overwrite = TRUE
                          )
```

When I run `golem::run_dev()`, the `firebase.rds` is generated in the app directory and app works fine. But when I do `devtools::check()`, I get the error:

```
── Error ('test-golem-recommended.R:55:1'): (code run outside of `test_that()`) ──
Error: Cannot find configuration file, see `?firebase_config`
```

What do I need to change for the `check` to pass?